# index results of two queries in a single array, using expressjs mysql, nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, express

my question is how can I form a result like this

```
[
  {
    "id_user": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "last_name": "bar",
    "id_rol": {
        "id_rol": 1,
        "rol_name": "admin"
    }
},
{
    "id_user": 2,
    "name": "foo2",
    "last_name": "bar2",
    "id_rol": {
        "id_rol": 2,
        "rol_name": "reporter"
    }
}
```

]

**considering** that I have two queries one users and another role
**the users**

```
[
{
    "id_user": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "last_name": "bar",
    "id_rol": 1
```

}
]

**the rols**

```
[
{
    "id_rol": 1,
    "rol_name": "foo"
}
```

]

basically I need to form an object with the id_rol, rol_name instead of the id,
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes users only have one role each. It also assumes that the list of roles always has the user role.

Basically, loop through the users. For each user get their role id. Use the role id to filter out the role that matches and assign it to the user object.

```
function mapRoleToUsers(users, roles) {
    for(let user of users) {
        let userRoleId = user.id_rol
        let userRole = roles.filter((role)=>{return role.id_rol == userRoleId})
        user.id_rol = userRole[0]
    }
}
```